# Linux :Can't start up: not enough memory

Tags: java, linux

I wrote a small java application and also wrote a small linux script to execute this Java program under Linux server .

But when ever i am trying to run this linux script  , i am getting this Error

**Can't start up: not enough memory**

Could anybody please help me in how to resolve this ??

This is my Script

```
echo "Start time: " `date`

SERVER_HOME=$HOME/

export CLASSPATH=.:

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH$SERVER_HOME/home/kiran/apiToplist/lib/*:

echo $CLASSPATH


java -cp $CLASSPATH -Xmx2G com.tata.samples.QuoteData
echo "End time: " `date`
```

Comment: I like your notion of "small"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need 2GB of memory for a *small* java application?  The value -Xmx2G tells the jmv to reserve 2GB of memory for your application.  If this is not available it will not work.

If 2GB is not needed, consider removing the value or lowering it.

Comment: +1: I wouldn't set the maximum heap size unless you know you need to.

Answer (score 2):

For Red Hat based systems, check to see if you are using GNU libgjc:

```
java -version

java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
```

Installing OpenJDK fixed the issue for me:

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
```

Read more about [Installing OpenJDK on Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Installation_Guide/Install_OpenJDK_on_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux.html)

Confirm that java has been updated:

```
java -version

java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.3.3.el6-x86_64 u45-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Start your java application.

Answer (score 1):

A 2G heap allocation is very large, and on some 32bit JVMs its larger than is permitted.

Try reducing the heap allocation to something smaller (using `-Xmx`), or use a 64bit JVM (which can have much larger heaps).

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a resource problem, try and reduce the value for Xmx flag. Have a look [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t390567-how-is-the-max-value-that-you-can-set-with-the-xmx-param-for-heap-size-of-the-java-jvm-determined.html).